# getting the manufacturer serial number of a flash disc in Delphi

Tags: delphi, usb, serial-number

I have tried all the code displayed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292395/how-to-get-manufacturer-serial-number-of-an-usb-flash-drive) on my usb flash disk with windows XP sp3, it always return this message "I/O error 105" without displaying any serial. what is the solution ?

Comment: The start of the solution is to post your code and some information about how you're running it, so we have something to go by. Saying "I get an error `I/O error 105` with my code. What's wrong with it?" without posting the code too makes it really hard to answer you. :-) I/O Error 105 is "File not open for output", caused by using `Write` or `WriteLn` while not running in a console window.

Comment: Maybe are you using the `Writeln` method in a VCL Form application?