# USB flash drive manufacturer serial number

Tags: java, serial-number, usb-flash-drive

How can I retrieve the manufacturer serial number of an USB flash drive in java?

i look at this

[How to get manufacturer serial number of an USB flash drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292395/how-to-get-manufacturer-serial-number-of-an-usb-flash-drive)

but it doesn't help me.

Comment: In Windows, you can use `Files.getFileStore(path).getAttribute("volume:vsn")`.  I'm not aware of any way to get it in other operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a pure Java solution for this that works across multiple platforms.

You will probably need to resort to "scraping" the output of an external command.  (Or figure out what they are doing, and replicate it in a native code library ...)

On Linux:

- The "lsusb" command's output includes the serial number.  (Check the manual entry.)

On Windows:

- Third-party commands called "usp64" and "USBDeview" do this: see http://ashfaqshinwary.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-find-usb-serial-number-from-windows/.
- Apparently, you can use `wmic` to get the serial number, though you may need to apply a Microsoft fix to make it work: https://superuser.com/questions/600394/get-usb-key-manufacturer-serial-number

---

@FoggyDay has found a couple of 3rd-party libraries that supposedly support this:

- [jUSB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/) is apparently only available for GNU/Linux.
- [usb4java](http://usb4java.org/) supports a wider range of platforms.
- Both depends on platform specific native libraries.

---

<sup>The comment that suggests using `Files.getFileStore(path).getAttribute("volume:vsn")` is incorrect, I think.  The Java source code implies that that is returning a volume serial number that is assigned by Windows, not the manufacturer-provided serial number.  The relevant code is [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/nio/fs/WindowsNativeDispatcher.java#WindowsNativeDispatcher.VolumeInformation).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The [jUSB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/) library allows you to read this from [usb.core.Configuration](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/apidoc/usb/core/Configuration.html).

[usb4java](http://usb4java.org) - another, newer Java library - probably also supports the same.

Comment: According to the documenation, jUSB requires GNU/Linux.  The usb4java library requires a port of the native "libusb" library, which is apparently available for a range of platforms.

Answer (score 0):

this method help you to read USB's sereal number

```
    public static String getSerialNumber() {
    String command = "powershell.exe Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | Select-Object SerialNumber\n";
    String serialNumber = null;
    try {
        Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
        BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("PowerShell output: " + line);
            if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                serialNumber = line.trim();
            }
        }
        stdout.close();
        BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        stderr.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return serialNumber;
}
```